# Extracting part of file name with sed and pattern matching

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file names like

```
KPMG_MRC_REVS_DAILY_YYYYMMDD.txt
eFrice_Derivatives_Revs_Daily_YYYYMMDD.txt
```

I want to identify the pattern `YYYYMMDD` and 
strip the string before the pattern.

for e.g I need to extract  `KPMG_MRC_REVS_DAILY_` as the output

how might I do this with sed?

for e.g

`echo "KPMG_MRC_REVS_DAILY_YYYYMMDD.txt" |sed "some regx g"`

Comment: What did you try so far ?  ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "KPMG_MRC_REVS_DAILY_YYYYMMDD.txt" | sed -E 's/[0-9]{8}//'
```

Works if you never have 8 digits, other than the date tag, in the file name.

**[0-9]{8}**: mean 8 digits that follow one another.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ echo "KPMG_MRC_REVS_DAILY_20181101.txt" | perl -ne ' { s/(.*)_(\d+)\.txt/\2/g ; print } '
20181101
```